# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch' and 'logout'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, redux

i dont understand what is the problem with this code. Most of the times i am facing this issue and still not able to resolve.

```
const logout = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
    dispatch({
      type: "EMPTY_CART",
    });
    history.push("/");
    setUser(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getEachUserCart(user?.result?._id));

    const token = user?.token;
    setShowCartInfor(false);
    // JWT..
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = decode(token);

      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) logout();
    }
    setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")));
  }, [location, user?.result?._id, user?.token]);
```

Comment: But i need to call that function later on. As an example whenever i click Logout button, the logout function will be triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is reported by your linter which says that you need to provide the dependency array according to the closure values you are using in the component.

To fix the warning you can update your code to `add logout as a dependency` to `useEffect` and use **`useCallback` to declare logout function**

```
const logout = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
    dispatch({
      type: "EMPTY_CART",
    });
    history.push("/");
    setUser(null);
  }, [history, dispatch, setUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getEachUserCart(user?.result?._id));

    const token = user?.token;
    setShowCartInfor(false);
    // JWT..
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = decode(token);

      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) logout();
    }
    setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")));
  }, [location, user?.result?._id, user?.token, logout]);
```

---

You can fix the warning by moving the logout function within the useEffect too if it is not being called from elsewhere

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    const logout = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY_CART",
        });
        history.push("/");
        setUser(null);
      };
    dispatch(getEachUserCart(user?.result?._id));

    const token = user?.token;
    setShowCartInfor(false);
    // JWT..
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken = decode(token);

      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) logout();
    }
    setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")));
  }, [location, user?.result?._id, user?.token]);
```

Comment: Thanks that the first solution worked well. Can you please explain why this happens?

Comment: React hooks work on the principle of closures in javascript. so If you are not specifying a value in dependency array, the useEffect will not run if that value changes. Normally function are not expected to change but it they use certain values from closures, they need to receive update values. This is why eslint missing dependency rules warns users to add appropriate dependencies that are used within a block of code so that unintentional issues related to closures are avoided.

Comment: @MuhammadHassaanAther Consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped