# React JS doesn't render on first time

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-hooks, use-effect

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import fire from "../../../config";
import { useAuth } from "../../AuthContext";
import { Grid, Paper, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./style.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import UserReviewComponent from "./UserReviewComponent";
import ReviewComponent from "../Reviews/ReviewComponent";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";

export default function UserReviews() {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState();
  const [state, setstate] = useState();
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const refItem = fire.firestore().collection("User");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState([true]);
  const [vendorDetails, setVendorDetails] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserDetails();
    fetchUserReviews();
  }, []);

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);

  const usersPerPage = 2;
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * usersPerPage;

  const pageCount = Math.ceil(users.length / usersPerPage);

  const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
    setPageNumber(selected);
  };

  const displayUsers = users
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + usersPerPage)
    .map((v) => {
      return (
        <ReviewComponent
          vendorid={v.vendorId}
          rating={v.rating}
          review={v.review}
          useremail={v.useremail}
          username={v.username}
          userid={v.userid}
          date={v.date}
          id={v.id}
        />
      );
    });

  const fetchUserReviews = () => {
    fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("VendorReviews")
      .where("useremail", "==", currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const item = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          item.push(doc.data());
        });
        setReviews(item);
        setUsers(reviews.slice(0, 50));
      });
  };
  const fetchUserDetails = () => {
    refItem.doc(currentUser.email).onSnapshot((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        setstate(doc.data().status);
        setPhoto(doc.data().photourl);
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    });
  };
  // const getTotalUserRating = () => {
  //   let totalRating = 0;
  //   reviews.map((v) => {
  //     totalRating += v.rating;
  //   });
  //   setRating(totalRating);
  //   setLoading(false);
  // };
  // if (loading) {
  //   return <div className="App">Loading...</div>;
  // }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-1">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <div id="content" className="content content-full-width">
              <div className="profile-1">
                <div className="profile-header">
                  <div className="profile-header-cover"></div>

                  <div className="profile-header-content">
                    <div className="profile-header-img">
                      <img src={photo} alt="" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="profile-header-info">
                      <h4 className="m-t-10 m-b-5">
                        {currentUser.displayName}
                      </h4>
                      <p className="m-b-10">{state}</p>
                      <Link
                        to={`/user/${currentUser.uid}`}
                        className="btn btn-sm btn-info mb-2"
                      >
                        Edit Profile
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <ul className="profile-header-tab nav nav-tabs">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <a
                        href="#profile-post"
                        className="nav-link active show"
                        data-toggle="tab"
                      >
                        My Reviews
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="container">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <div className="offer-dedicated-body-left">
                    <div className="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                      <div
                        className="tab-pane fade active show"
                        id="pills-reviews"
                        role="tabpanel"
                        aria-labelledby="pills-reviews-tab"
                      >
                        <div className="bg-white rounded shadow-sm p-4 mb-4 restaurant-detailed-ratings-and-reviews">
                          <h5 className="mb-1">All Ratings and Reviews</h5>
                          {displayUsers}

                          <hr />
                          <hr />
                          <a
                            className="text-center w-100 d-block mt-4 font-weight-bold"
                            href="#"
                          >
                            <ReactPaginate
                              previousLabel={"Previous"}
                              nextLabel={"Next"}
                              pageCount={pageCount}
                              onPageChange={changePage}
                              containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
                              previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
                              nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
                              disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
                              activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                            />
                          </a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

If I edit something on the IDE and then save and then the content appears but there is nothing on the first render. Please help me out. I think its due to pagination and the array has undefined values on the first render and so it returns nothing. The pagination slices the array so that the pagination is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

add following in useEffects dependency array

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserDetails();
    fetchUserReviews();
   }, [reviews, state, photo, users ]);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @Hassaan, it solved the problem but there are too many re-renders.

Comment: Yup, i knew it will happern, its react-exhaustive issue, you can use useCallback on your function,     const fetchUserReviews = useCallback(() => { },[]) 
  const fetchUserDetails = useCallback (() => { },[])                            If it still dont sove issue you should check this out.             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093896/react-hook-useeffect-has-missing-dependencies-dispatch-and-logout-either-i